# alter word keeping the punctuation mark in its own position

Tags: php

I want a program in php that takes the first letter of word to the last and add "ay" at end. example:
`I love my family` becomes `Iay ovelay ymay amilyfay`

I did this to get my result:

```
<?php
$var = "I love my family";
$words = explode(" ",$var);
$final = "";
foreach ($words as $word){
    $n = "";
    for($i=1;$i<strlen($word);$i++){
        $n .= $word{$i};
    }
    $n .= $word{0}."ay";
    $final .= $n." ";
}
echo $final;
?>
```

but this doesnt work when the input is: `he says, "I love my family"`. this gives output as: `ehay ays,say I"ay ovelay ymay amily"fay` where I need the punctuation marks to be in their own position like this: `ehay ayssay, "Iay ovelay ymay amilyfay"`

Tried alot but found nothing that works

Comment: Have you tried the `to_pig_latin` function?

Comment: no, let me google and try that

Comment: Heh I was kidding, writing up an answer now..

Comment: Instead research regex. It's a one-liner without the explode and loop workaround.

Comment: @Marty Actually, if you google `php pig latin` you'll find some scripts that do it.

Comment: I am gonna need the shortest answer. http://chys.info/eng/piglatin I found this but it looks like that gonna make a big deal to do the task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something along the lines of:

```
$str = 'he says, "I love my family"';
$str = preg_replace('/(\w{1})(\w*)/', "$2$1ay", $str);

echo $str; // ehay ayssay, "Iay ovelay ymay amilyfay"
```

Should get you at least most of the way there.

Comment: should be `ehay ayssay, "Iay ovelay ymay amilyfay"`